# System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock running twice

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe

I am registering a script block on a button click. But when i do a refresh frame the script runs again. Is there a way to remedy this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you checking to see if it's already registered?

[RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx#Y114)

```
    String csName = "ButtonClickScript";
    Type csType = this.GetType();

    // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

    // Check to see if the client script is already registered.
    if (!cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(csType, csName))
    {
      StringBuilder csText = new StringBuilder();
      csText.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> function DoClick() {");
      csText.Append("Form1.Message.value='Text from client script.'} </");
      csText.Append("script>");
      cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, csName, csText.ToString());
    }
```